# How to display progress bar while initializing large data during class init

Tags: python, events, pyqt5, initialization

I'm using PyQt5.
During MainWindow.__init__ in the code below, I want to initialize some large data (see MainWindow.initData) that takes a long time (20 seconds for example).  During that time, I would like to display a progress bar.  The progress bar cannot be displayed until after app.exec_() starts executing, thus I cannot call initData from within  MainWindow.__init__.  So I'm trying to execute initData by posting an event (postEvent) that will cause initData to execute while app.exec_ is executing.  I looked at some examples in stackoverflow and arrived at the following code.  The event does get posted and initData is called, but the progress bar is not displayed until after initData is completed.

Please advise on how to revise the code so that the progress bar will be displayed while initData is executing.  Thanks.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent

class MyEvent(QEvent):
    idType = QEvent.registerEventType()

    def __init__(self, data):
        QEvent.__init__(self, MyEvent.idType)
        self.data = data
        print("MyEvent.idType ", MyEvent.idType)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("My MainWindow")
        self.qProgressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.qProgressBar.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 30)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello", self)
        self.label.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 20)

        tempEvent = MyEvent("12345")
        QtWidgets.QApplication.postEvent(self, tempEvent)

    def initData(self):
        # To demonstrate, do something that takes a long time (for example
        # 20 seconds) and update progress bar.
        print("begin initData")
        loop = 10000
        for i in range(loop):
            self.qProgressBar.setValue(int((i+1)/loop*100))
            for j in range(loop):
                temp = i + j

    def customEvent(self, event):
        print("customEvent:", event.type())
        if (event.type() == MyEvent.idType):
            self.label.setText("Received : {0}".format(event.get_data()))
            self.initData()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    w.setGeometry(screen.width()//2-200, screen.height()//2-200, 400, 400) # x, y, Width, Height
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Instead of trying to use customEvent, why don't you just use a basic QThread to initialize the data, which will also give you the ability to use signals to properly update the progress bar?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm fairly new to Python/PyQt5 and don't understand what you are suggesting.  But I will research your suggestions.  If you could suggest actual code modification, that would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: I cannot modify your code, as it would almost mean to completely rewrite it. In practice, you'll need to implement a *worker thread* (which will be a subclass of QThread) and create a custom signal for it, which will possibly emit progress status, then in the main window you create an instance of that thread, connect its signal to a function that updates the progress bar, and start it. Do some research on the subjects above and you'll find lots of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks musicamante.  Here is the final result that works!

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from time import sleep

class Worker_InitData(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(1)
            self.progress.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("My MainWindow")
        self.qProgressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self)
        self.qProgressBar.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 30)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello", self)
        self.label.setGeometry(50, 50, 200, 20)

        self.initData()

    def reportProgress(self, i):
        self.qProgressBar.setValue(int((i+1)/10*100))
    
    def initData(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker_InitData()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    screen = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    w.setGeometry(screen.width()//2-200, screen.height()//2-200, 400, 400) # x, y, Width, Height
    w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note that generally it's not required to use a QObject subclass and then use `moveToThread` on a QThread, as you can just subclass QThread and override its `run()` method.